# How can I show three levels of children in a custom REST API?

Tags: soql, rest-api

We're building an data inventory system in salesforce and we want to expose the records via a public REST API. I've created an anonymous REST API (no authentication required) and I can expose one object's records at a time, but I'd like to include their nested children. The problem is you can only nest one layer deep, so I'm looking for alternatives.

**Datasets** have many **Views** which have many **Endpoints**

I'd like to expose something like (simplified):

`[
   {
      "dataset_name": "Crimes",
      "views": [
         {
            "view_name": "Public",
            "endpoints": [
               {
                  "endpoint_name": "CSV",
                  "endpoint_url": "http://foo/bar.csv"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "view_name": "Private",
            "endpoints": [
               {
                  "endpoint_name": "CSV",
                  "endpoint_url": "http://foo.internal/bar-internal.csv"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]`

A nested query would solve this perfectly if we could go multiple layers deep, ie:

`SELECT Name, (SELECT Name, (SELECT Name, URL__c FROM Endpoints__r) FROM Views__r) FROM Dataset__c`

But you can only go one level deep, so I can't get the endpoints in. What are my other options? I was considering:

A) Get all the datasets with a basic query, then loop through the datasets and query its views + endpoints. But this hits a SOQL query limit.

B) Somehow include `endpoints` as a field on `views` so it doesn't require a subquery?

I'm very new to salesforce but I have a background in javascript and php, so I'm not as familiar with custom objects and fields but I get the code part.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you'll need to write an apex REST service that does the two SOQLs and then assembles the results in a data structure that SFDC will serialize back as the REST reponse

Comment: You mean query all the `datasets` and then query all the `views + endpoints` and combine them together by mapping on the `datasets.id` and `views.dataset_id` fields?

Comment: That would be one approach; you could also query (1) datasets + views, then (2) build a set of unique viewIds from result of (1) , (3) query all endPoints where viewId IN set returned from (2), and (4) append to your data structure built in (1) the results from (3). You'll need to use maps to avoid linear searching your nested lists.